# Django nested queries

Tags: django, python-3.x, mariadb

In Django I'm trying to achieve a nested SQL structure like this without using raw queries:

```sql
SELECT id, 
   session_hash, 
   user_id, 
   price_type_id, 
   room_category_id, 
   check_in_date, 
   price, 
   captured_date 
FROM   (SELECT p.*, 
           Row_number() OVER (partition BY check_in_date, price_type_id, room_category_id ORDER BY captured_date DESC) AS rn 
    FROM   dashboard_prices p 
    WHERE  room_category_id = 1 
           AND price_type_id = 1 
           AND check_in_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' 
           AND check_in_date <= '2018-01-02 00:00:00') p 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

I couldn't figure out how to achieve that by using "normal" query expressions in Django.

#### Model:

```py
class Prices(models.Model):
    session_hash = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    price_type = models.ForeignKey(PriceTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    room_category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    check_in_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    captured_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    row_number = 'row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY check_in_date, price_type_id, room_category_id ' \
             'ORDER BY captured_date DESC)'
```

I achieved already to get the inner query running by:

```py
price = Prices.objects.annotate(rn=RawSQL(Prices.row_number[]))
    .filter(room_category_id=req['room_category_id'], price_type_id=req['price_type_id'],
            check_in_date__gte=check_in_date, check_in_date__lte=check_out_date)
```

But filtering after this brings only errors:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause
```

when adding:

```
.filter(rn=1)
```

Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Thanks!